# Were Soviet missions to Skylab ever considered?

Tags: history, soviet-union, skylab

The question [How was Skylab's orbit inclination chosen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35410/how-was-skylabs-orbit-inclination-chosen) gave some rationale as to why Skylab was in such a high inclination (close to today's ISS at 51.6).

Was there ever consideration (during and after the [Apollo-Soyuz Test Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz_Test_Project)) to allowing/requesting the Soviets to conduct manned missions to Skylab?

Comment: Keep in mind that prior to Skylab, the only previous manned space station was Salyut 1.  The first mission to it failed to dock, and the second mission ended in the death of the three cosmonauts on re-entry.  Three more space stations were launched and failed.  So I don't think the Soviets were much in the mood for going to Skylab.